# Shear force in a beam at ends

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, stresses

Consider a cantilever beam acted upon by a point load at its free end. The shear force diagram is shown.

I have a little doubt,is the shear force at x= 0 ,both 0 and $-W$ or just $-W$? Similarly at the fixed end, is the shear force 0 or $-W$, or both?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I manage these types of problems in my head (as an engineer that likes math) is the following:

At

- $x= 0^-$ the shear force is 0
- $x= 0^+$ the shear force is -W
- $x=0$ is a singularity point and both and none are strictly correct

Where the notation

- $a^-$ is for a number close to $a$ approaching from minus infinity.
- $a^+$ is for a number close to $a$ approaching from plus infinity.

similarly at:

- $x= L^-$ the shear force is -W
- $x= L^+$ the shear force is 0
- $x=L$ is (again) a singularity point

---

After a while you stop thinking about these type of problems, because they are not really (or more precisely **they shouldn't be**) affecting the solution.

Comment: I was thinking about something similar, however I face an issue with this approach. When I'm talking about a section at $x= 0^-$ I'm basically not in the beam, so shear force should hold no meaning. Same goes for $x=L^+$. So by that logic shear force at x= 0 and L should be -W, not 0. What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: On this specific example, yes the $x=0^-$ the point is not part of the beam. However, that doesn't negate the fact that the value there *should* be zero. In the case though, where $x=a$  and $0<a<L$ and there is a change in shear force, then this is very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the body should always be in equilibrium. This means that the load applied by the support on the body should be equal but in the opposite direction to that what is applied to the body by you. Opposite is important, not the sign or direction. You can assign upwards as positive or downwards as positive, it doesn't matter. If you apply (+) load, then reaction should be equal but (-), but if you apply (-) load, then reaction force should be (+).

It doesn't matter from where you are taking the x, it matters which part of the body (after being cut) are you considering. For example, imagine you cut the part in the middle and x is taken from the left end side where the load is applied. Now, if you are taking the left part of the body, then there needs to exist an internal shear force at the cut location in the opposite direction to the applied load, to ensure equilibrium.

If you take the other part now (which is connected to the support), then the shear force should be in the same direction as the applied load because the only external load acting on it is the reaction load, which is infact in the opposite direction to the applied load. So to make this part become stable, you need to have an internal shear force at the cut location which should be in the same direction and having the same sign as the external applied load, in order to ensure equilibrium.